# How to get the most top frame or window frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Lets say I have the following structure.

[image]

**Actually the red one is JDialog.** 
My question is how to get the black main frame inside of the red jdialog so that I can change something of the black frame. They are not parent-children relationship.

Is there any method I can used to get the window first then get the black frame?

I heard that SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor might be able to do something I want. I tried and did not succeed.

Comment: Should you really have multiple JFrames at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice

Comment: If you need to change the parent you will need to supply some kind of reference to the parent, either directly (which I would discourage) or via some kind of model/controller which you can ask to apply the changes on your behalf in some way

Comment: I second @MadProgrammer's recs. Of course the devil's all in the details, meaning the details of the solution will depend exquisitely on the details of your code and your problem. I am just a little concerned when you state "parent", because inheritance has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: You can get an array of all "ownerless windows" created by your application by calling `Window.getOwnerlessWindows()` on one of the windows of the application, but again, I have to reiterate what @MadProgrammer states, that you're far better off changing the state of a model, and then having each "view" respond to the change according to its own behaviors.

Comment: *"They are not parent-children relationship."*  Why?  A child of a particular parent does not have to be modal, but there are other advantages of linking them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shoot at this in many different ways. Depending if you need just a one time solution or a dynamic one, the strategy therefor changes. As a one time solution if you just always want to find the main frame, you could either use a reference as already suggested by others or make a singleton main frame, where you just access it like `MainFrame.getInstance().doWhateveryouwanted();`

However it is not clear which target you are up to, I throw some helpful methods in:

```
    Frame[] frames = JFrame.getFrames();
    for (Frame frame : frames) {
        if (frame.isActive()) {
            return frame;
        }
    }
    for (Frame frame : frames) {
        if (frame.isVisible()) {
            return frame;
        }
    }
```

Based on the SwingUtilities class, there are other very helpful methods, look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html).
Check out `SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponent() or SwingUtilities.getAccessibleAt()`